# Access to windows server share prompt for credentials on Windows 7

Tags: windows, networking, share, server, credentials

Since I have restarted one of my DC (I have previously check if it owned FSMO roles), windows 7 domain computers ask for credentials to access network shares.
Bellow the prompt Windows, there is an error message about wrong credentials.
I have check the credential store with no success.
No problem with Windows XP clients with same user account.
No error in event log (I have enable the account audit functionnality).
Reboot of file server and clients do nothing.
Thanks for your help.

In addition, we have lot of entries in the event log 4625:

Sujet :
    ID de sécurité :        NULL SID
    Nom du compte :     -
    Domaine du compte :     -
    ID d’ouverture de session :     0x0

Type d’ouverture de session :           3

Compte pour lequel l’ouverture de session a échoué :
    ID de sécurité :        NULL SID
    Nom du compte :     username
    Domaine du compte :     domain.local

Informations sur l’échec :
    Raison de l’échec :     Une erreur s’est produite lors de l’ouverture de session.
    État :          0xc000006d
    Sous-état :     0x0

Informations sur le processus :
    ID du processus de l’appelant : 0x0
    Nom du processus de l’appelant :    -

Informations sur le réseau :
    Nom de la station de travail :  computer
    Adresse du réseau source :  -
    Port source :       -

Informations détaillées sur l’authentification :
    Processus d’ouverture de session :      NtLmSsp
    Package d’authentification :    NTLM
    Services en transit :   -
    Nom du package (NTLM uniquement) :  -
    Longueur de clé :       0

Cet événement est généré lorsqu’une demande d’ouverture de session échoue. Il est généré sur l’ordinateur sur lequel l’accès a été tenté.

Le champ Objet indique le compte sur le système local qui a demandé l’ouverture de session. Il s’agit le plus souvent d’un service, comme le service Serveur, ou un processus local tel que Winlogon.exe ou Services.exe.

Le champ Type d’ouverture de session indique le type d’ouverture de session qui a été demandé. Les types les plus courants sont 2 (interactif) et 3 (réseau).

Les champs relatifs aux informations sur le processus indiquent quel est le compte et le processus sur le système qui ont demandé l’ouverture de session.

Les champs relatifs aux informations sur le réseau indiquent la provenance de la demande d’ouverture de session distante. Le nom de la station de travail n’étant pas toujours disponible, peut rester vide dans certains cas.

Les champs relatifs aux informations d’authentification fournissent des détails sur cette demande d’ouverture de session spécifique.
    - Les services en transit indiquent les services intermédiaires qui ont participé à cette demande d’ouverture de session.
    - Le nom du package indique quel a été le sous-protocole qui a été utilisé parmi les protocoles NTLM.
    - La longueur de la clé indique la longueur de la clé de session générée. Elle a la valeur 0 si aucune clé de session n’a été demandée.

Answer (score -1):

I have found the solution.
This is the technet [link](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/14983471-b25a-4bb6-81e0-aa63bed9b4ac/event-id-4625-null-sid-error?forum=winserver8gen) that addresses this problem.
I have installed on my DC the KB3002657-v2 and things are back to normal.
Thx.